# Sign a dll using cmd

Tags: .net, dll, dllregistration

I have a dll (project.dll) I want to sign the dll using cmd as I don't have source code of it.

Is it possible to sign a dll without sourcecode.

If yes, please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only sign assemblies after they have been compiled. Having the source code is irrelevant.

Use the [`sn.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23.aspx), and [`al.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx) tools.

See how to use them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx).

Comment: what is mymodule.netmodule in the given example al /out:MyAssembly.dll MyModule.netmodule /keyfile:sgKey.snk

Comment: @vaibhav - It is the namespace being signed.